# Функции с места вызова или вложеность

Tags: javascript, функции

Зачем вызывать функции с места чтобы не загрязнять общую область видимости его локальными переменными, если можно просто использовать вложенность?

То есть зачем делать что-то такое

```
 var obj = (function(){
  function changeColor(){...}
  .....
  return {
   document.getElementById('id').onclick = changeColor
  }
 })()
```

Если можно сделать так:

```
function colorEl(){
  document.getElementById('id').onclick = changeColor
  function changeColor(){...}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, разница очевидна. Во втором случае Вы можете сколь угодное кол-во раз вызвать `colorEl`, в то время как в первом случае вызов единственен, да ещё и не добавляет функций в глобальное пространство имён.

---

В данном случае пример использования `(function{}())` надуманный и я бы даже сказал неуместен, подробнее тут: [(function() {})(); Для чего используется такая конструкция?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/124327/)

Comment: да кстати а вот в первом варианте, она же выполнится до DOM обработки, то есть   document.getElementById('id') это не прокатит, как этого избежать?

Comment: поместить код в `domReady` или `onLoad` в чём проблема?

Comment: так это как-то не смотрится(

Comment: не спорю, но вопрос был о разнице, а не эстетической стороне применения, в данном случае пример использования `(function{}())` надуманный и я бы даже сказал неуместен, подробнее тут: [(function() {})(); Для чего используется такая конструкция?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/124327/)